# XMLTYPE Extract multiple paths / Indexing

Tags: xml, oracle, indexing, extract, xmltype

I have a table "TEST" with a CLOB column "XML" (DB Oracle 11), where the content of xml's are saved.

In this columns you find for example rows with such content

1 Row

```
<xml>
     <identification>Test1</identification>
<xml>
```

2 Row

```
<xml>
    <identificationNumber>Test2</identificationNumber>
<xml>
```

A normal Extract goes like this:

```
    Select
    XMLTYPE("TEST"."XML").EXTRACT('//identification/text()').getStringVal()
    From "XML"
```

**1. Question**

How can i extract from two Paths? As both name the same, and are for example just a mistake in an xml.

**2. Question**

While having much extracts in one select, for performance it could be better to index, or?

How can i index an Extract like above?

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**

If the nodes are in the same place in the hierarchy, you can use something like this:

```
SQL> create table test (xml clob)
  2  /

Table created.

SQL> insert into test
  2  select '<xml>
  3       <identification>Test1</identification>
  4  </xml>' from dual union all
  5  select '<xml>
  6      <identificationNumber>Test2</identificationNumber>
  7  </xml>' from dual
  8  /

2 rows created.

SQL> select XMLTYPE("TEST"."XML").EXTRACT('/xml//text()').getStringVal()
  2    from test
  3  /

XMLTYPE("TEST"."XML").EXTRACT('/XML//TEXT()').GETSTRINGVAL()
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test1
Test2

2 rows selected.
```

**Question 2**

In this example, an index probably won't do you any good. But in general, here are some links about XML indexes:

- [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb_indexing.htm#CHDJECDA)
- [Marco Gralike's blog](http://www.liberidu.com/blog/2007/07/10/oracle-11g-xmlindex-part-1/)